# C3857 multiple type parameter lists are not allowed Compiler error

Tags: c++

this snippet causes the above error, why? How can i fix it.

```
class SimpleLogger
{

public:
    enum{ LogSeverityLevel = SWB_LOG_LEVEL };

    template<int level>
   out_policy<bigger_policy<level, SWB_LOG_LEVEL>::value> out; //C3857

   ~SimpleLogger(){}
};
```

EDIT:
as asked the definition of is bigger and the exact compiler error

```
struct is_bigger_equal;
struct is_not_bigger_equal;

template<int first, int second>
struct bigger_policy
{
    enum{ value = bigger_policy<first - 1, second - 1>::value };
};

template<>
struct bigger_policy<0, 0>
{
    enum{ value = 1 };
};

template<int second>
struct bigger_policy<0,second>
{
    enum{ value = 1 };
};

template<int first>
struct bigger_policy<first, 0>
{
    enum{ value = 0 };
};
```

exact error is c3857: multiple type parameter lists are not allowed

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyd059h3.aspx has some solutions, do you have trouble with solving these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to declare a "template variable," but there's no such thing. A member variable (or any other variable) cannot be a template on its own. It can be a member of a *class template*, though. Maybe you can apply the `template <int level>` to the class instead, turning `SimpleLogger` into a class template parameterized by a `level` value:

```
template <int level>
class SimpleLogger
{
public:
  enum{ LogSeverityLevel = SWB_LOG_LEVEL };

  out_policy<bigger_policy<level, SWB_LOG_LEVEL>::value> out;

  ~SimpleLogger(){}
};
```

Whether that's acceptable to you depends on what you were hoping to get in the first place.